How to upgrade firebase extension functions to gen 2
I want to upgrade this firebase function created from extension Trigger Email from Firestore to gen 2. How can I do it ?

I tried to find documents or some information useful but I found nothing related to gen 2 firebase extension

You can't change that while still using it as an extension.  Firebase Extension source code and deployment is entirely handled by Firebase, and you can only change how they work using the documented parameters.  You can't simply choose a v2 deployment - the system will deploy whatever is shown in the source code.
You can see the source code for the extension yourself.  The import shows clearly that it's using the v1 SDK:
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

If you really need a v2 function, you can always copy the source code, modify it, and deploy it yourself.  Or you can file an issue on GitHub to request a change.  At that point, you are no longer getting the conveniences of a Firebase Extension, as you are choosing to manage it yourself.

Thanks for the information, Doug but I want to ask if in the future, firestore-send-mail does have 2nd gen functions then when I click update button in the Firebase Extension screen will it automatically upgrade my function to gen 2 or I have to remove the function and install it again

I don't know what's going to happen in the future.
